# matplotlib: display plots sequentially in web browser when running ipython from command line

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

Current, I get 3 separate windows with pyplot... which i don't want... i want to see all of my plots sequentially listed "inline" in a single web browser window similar to jupyter output except with my script running from a windows command line as an ipython script...

```
# File: plotit.ipy

# toy ipython plotting example
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
%matplotlib

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y1 = 5*t
y2 = -0.5*t
y3 = 2*t**2

# display as 1st inline graph in "jupyter web browser window"
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,y1)
plt.show()

# display as 2nd inline graph in "jupyter web browser window"
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,y2)
plt.show()

# display as 3rd inline graph in "jupyter web browser window"
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,y3, '.')
plt.show()
```

This is how I run it from command line using ActiveState Python 3.6:

```
C:\> ipython 
In [1]: %run testit.ipy
Using matplotlib backend: TkAgg
```

Is there's a way to convert a Jupiter document into a ipython script, and run it from the command line as one monolithic script, but still have the matplotlib plots show up "inline" in a jupyter output window sequentially as they are plotted while running the script.  Example:

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's possible to emulate a jupyter notebook, without actually running it.

An alternative could be to use the `webagg` backend. In this case only a single `plt.show()` call is put at the end to show all three figures on the same page.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("webagg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y1 = 5*t
y2 = -0.5*t
y3 = 2*t**2

# display as 1st inline graph in "jupyter web browser window"
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,y1)

# display as 2nd inline graph in "jupyter web browser window"
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,y2)

# display as 3rd inline graph in "jupyter web browser window"
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,y3, '.')
plt.show()
```

When running this a browser window should open, and show the three figures

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Save all plots as image files without displaying them, then write an html file to display all the image files after running python script.

```
# File: plotit.ipy

# toy ipython plotting example
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y1 = 5*t
y2 = -0.5*t
y3 = 2*t**2

# display as 1st inline graph in jupyter web browser window
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,y1)
fig.savefig("plot1.png")

# display as 2nd inline graph in jupyter web browser window
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,y2)
fig.savefig("plot2.png")

# display as 3rd inline graph in jupyter web browser window
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,y3)
fig.savefig("plot3.png")
```

html:

```
<!-- FILE: results.html -->
<html>
<body>
    <img src="plot1.png"/><br>
    <img src="plot2.png"/><br>
    <img src="plot3.png"/><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Another html results page:

```
<h1>Results</h1>

<table>

<tr>
<td><img src="plot1.png" style="max-width:100%"/></td>
<td><img src="plot2.png" style="max-width:100%"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><img src="plot3.png" style="max-width:100%"/></td>
<td><img src="plot1.png" style="max-width:100%"/></td>
</tr>

</table>
```